# Python code to replicate DOS Copy command - Binary

Tags: python, binary, concatenation, copy, dos

In DOS there is a simple command:  copy /b file1 file2 file3   This will do a Binary copy that concatenates file1+file2 outputting file3.

It may seem odd but I need to attach an existing file (xml) as part 1 and then a pdf file as part 2. This attaches a 'print' ticket to a print file(pdf). All the samples I see are 'merging' text files - NOT what I need. I can already do this in DOS but I dont want to use it - I need this functionality inside my Python script that is doing many other things that already work great.

Thanks for any tips or ideas!

Cannot find online any matches to my searches and cannot find similar descriptions using shutil.copy() commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can **append binary files with simple file operations**:

```
def append_bin_files(file1, file2, output_file):
    with open(file1, 'rb') as f1, open(file2, 'rb') as f2, open(output_file, 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(f1.read())
        fo.write(f2.read())

# use the function
append_bin_files('message.xml', 'ticket.pdf', 'output.bin')
```

This is fine for smaller files, which fit well into memory (using read() function).